# if my file not exist in android

Tags: android, file

I want if password.txt is exist program do nothing and go to next line and if password.txt not exist it create this file and write on it 123456
but program will write on password.txt 123456 anyway! where I did mistake?

```
    File file = new File(getExternalCacheDir(), "/sdcard/Robo/password.txt" );
                            if (!file.exists()) {
                                try {

                                    password="123456";
                                    File passfile = new     
                                    File("/sdcard/Robo/password.txt");
                                    passfile.createNewFile();
                                    FileOutputStream passout = new      
                                    FileOutputStream(passfile);
                                    OutputStreamWriter passoutw = new   
                                    OutputStreamWriter(passout);
                                    passoutw.append(password);
                                    passoutw.close();

                                    passout.close();

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.getMessage(),
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                            }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
File file = new File("/sdcard/Robo/password.txt" );
```